# Xpages: Bootstrap accordion controls not working correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, custom-controls

Trying to build a reusable menu custom control with a bootstrap theme. I would like an accordion layout, that looks like so:

[image]

In a true accordion when a user selects a different heading then the previously selected heading "rolls up". Mine is not rolling up. I suppose this is not a huge problem, but am concerned that if this is not working, then something else will not work either.

I am wondering if it would be better to use the dojo accordion in Xpages in this instance?

Custom Control code (ccMenuFinal)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" 
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

<style>
    .list-group{margin-bottom:0} 
</style>    

    <xp:div styleClass="panel-group" id="accordion">

    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" var="entry" indexVar="index"
        value="#{javascript:compositeData.mnuHeading}">

            <xp:div styleClass="panel panel-default">
                <xp:div styleClass="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-parent="#accordion"
                            href="#{javascript:'#' + entry.MenuHeadingName}">
                            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
                                value="#{javascript:entry.MenuHeadingName}" />
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </xp:div>


                <div id="#{javascript:entry.MenuHeadingName}"
                    class="panel-collapse collapse">

                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <xp:repeat id="repeat2" var="entry2"
                            indexVar="index2" value="#{javascript:entry.mnuTitle}">
                        <xp:link id="lnk"
                                value="#{javascript://entry2.mnuTrg}">
                                <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (entry2.mnuTrg == context.getUrl().getSiteRelativeAddress(context))
{"list-group-item active"}
else
{"list-group-item"}}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
                                <xp:image id="image3"
                                    style="padding-right:10.0px"
                                    url="#{javascript:entry2.mnuTtlIcn}">
                                </xp:image>
                                <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:entry2.mnuNme}]]></xp:this.text>
                            </xp:link>
                        </xp:repeat>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </xp:div>

    </xp:repeat>

    </xp:div>

</xp:view>
```

[image]

Xpage code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
<div class="container">
<xc:ccMenuFinal>
        <xc:this.mnuHeading>
            <xc:mnuHeading MenuHeadingName="PCs">
                <xc:this.mnuTitle>
                    <xc:mnuTitle mnuTrg="/xpView01.xsp"
                        mnuNme="Inventory"
                        mnuTtlIcn="/inventory16X16blue.png"
                        mnuTtlIcnAct="/inventory16X16.png">
                    </xc:mnuTitle>
                    <xc:mnuTitle mnuNme="Being Built"
                        mnuTrg="/xpView02.xsp" 
                        mnuTtlIcn="/build16X16blue.png"
                        mnuTtlIcnAct="/build16X16.png">
                    </xc:mnuTitle>
                </xc:this.mnuTitle>
            </xc:mnuHeading>
            <xc:mnuHeading MenuHeadingName="Tasks">
                <xc:this.mnuTitle>
                    <xc:mnuTitle mnuNme="Build Tasks"
                        mnuTrg="/xpViewTasksBuild.xsp">
                    </xc:mnuTitle>
                </xc:this.mnuTitle>
            </xc:mnuHeading>
        </xc:this.mnuHeading>
    </xc:ccMenuFinal>
 </div> 
</xp:view>
```

Comment: may be this can help you, http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/accordion-menu

Comment: Frank. Thanks. That is what I was basing my code from. My goal is to make a bootstrap like accordion menu which separates out the data from the programming, so that I can make the menu a custom control with the data for the menu some data structure. I can get this to work with a menu the tis one level, and has no accordions, but cannot get it to work with those two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the code you posted.

The first is your `<xp:div styleClass="panel-group" id="accordion">`

Because it's an XP tag, the id **accordion** gets converted into a programmatic id that consists of prefixes...e.g. `view:0:whatever:accordion`. This is breaking your tabs and not allowing them to link to the panel group. Change this to `<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">`

The second is the repeat control that is used to generate the tabs. As a default, a repeat control creates its own divs. This is creating alien HTML tags inside your accordion HTML. There is a property for the repeat control called **disableOutputTag**. Set this to true and it will remove the alien HTML.